# Why overriding both equals() and hashCode() in Java?

Tags: java, object, overriding, equals, hashcode

Maybe this question seems ridiculous for you, but I clearly do not understand (I am junior Java) why should we override `equals()` and `hashCode()` often together?

Indeed, I can override `equals()` for some class to make a specific comparing, but why should I override `hashCode()` too? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: there are tons of sources about this, no doubt your textbook also provides information about this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/override-equalsobject-hashcode-method/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265637/10476860 Even on SO there are some sources about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several collections like for example HashSet rely on the fact that `equals` and `hashCode` are consistent. That means that `hashCode` must give the same value when the objects are equal in the sense of `equals`.